# Pyparsing: word with at least one non-digit character

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

How does one define a pattern for a "word with at least one non-digit character" (anywhere in the word) using pyparsing Word() and friends?

The regex solution would be:

```
Regex("[a-z0-9]+[a-z][a-z0-9]+")
```

I tried things along the line of:

```
Combine(Optional(Word(alphanums)) & Word(alphas))
```

There must be a solution based on FollowedBy / NotAny / SkipTo but I have not figured that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually think the Regex you would want would be:

```
Regex("[0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*")
```

So putting this together using pyparsing classes would be:

```
Combine(Optional(Word(nums)) + Word(alphas,alphanums))
```

But at parse time, the Regex will be much faster.

Comment: Also, if you just want lowercase alphas (as implied by your Regex sample), change references to `alphas` and `alphanums` to `alphas.lower()` and `alphanums.lower()`.